# Show alert on press back button

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-alertdialog, back-button

I writing android app on Xamarin(C#)

I need to **Show alert with "Yes" and "No"** variantes when I tap **back button** on Activity.

How can I realize this?

I know how to show alert. How I can make it when i press back button

Comment: Please share your code or what you have tried. Without which we won't be able to help on what help you need. Current question is too vague and can have so many answers.

Comment: call alert dialog in click back button

Comment: How can I call dialog in click back button?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34207853/4984832

Comment: If any of the answers worked for you, it would be helpful for others if you accept that answer. If not, feel free to comment on the answers given, or update your question.

Answer (score 2):

try this , add to your activity

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder =
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
            builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
            builder.setMessage("" + Message);
            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    //write your code

                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("No", null);
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.show();
    }
```

Comment: So with the java code create your C# code. I most often creating C# code so that rewrite JAVA. On the internet you will not find much example in C# code for android (Xamarin).
It should not be that hard (C # for android is basically "just" Transcription Java functions and usually have the same names, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin provides wrappers to the native Android Activity classes. So you probably have a MainActivity and maybe other Activity classes in your Xamarin Android project.
In these classes you can override the OnBackPressed method inherited from FormsApplicationActivity and then create and show your Alert from there.

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
{
    public override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        // show Alert or pass call on to base.OnBackPressed()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Xamarin Forms 1.3.0 pre3, there is a new method:

```
protected bool OnBackButtonPressed();
```

You need to override this on your page.

```
    protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {    
         // If you want to stop the back button and show alert
         return true;

         // If you want to continue going back
          base.OnBackButtonPressed();
          return false; 
    }
```

Thanks to Xamarin Forums. Refer [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/29583/is-there-a-way-to-override-a-back-button-press-on-android) link for more info.